# Filtering all rows with a specific value, without specifiying column names

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I would like to filter a dataframe for rows that contain only False in every column. Because the number of columns and their names may vary I would like to do so without explicitly naming the columns. Column names from a list, or any function akin to pandas.DataFrame.all is fine. The index needs to be preserved.

```
bool_dict = {'one':[True, False, False,False], 'two':[False, True, True, False], 'three':[False,False,True,False]}
bool_df = pd.DataFrame(bool_dict)
```

Expected output is a dataframe comprising row index 3. i.e the result of this command

```
df_false = bool_df[(bool_df['one']==False) & (bool_df['two']==False) & (bool_df['three']==False)]
```

I'm sure there must be a simple solution, though I seem to be having trouble finding it. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `.any()` or `.all()` along `axis=1` to make it indifferent about the columns. Check if all are `False` either by:

```
bool_df[(~bool_df).all(1)]
# or
bool_df[~bool_df.any(1)]

#     one    two  three
#3  False  False  False
```

Comment: thank you so much, I doubt I would have thought of this. I'll mark this one as correct because it deals directly with boolean logic- though I do also appreciate the elegance of the sum/max solution below

Answer (score 4):

You may need `sum`

```
bool_df[bool_df.sum(1)==0]
     one  three    two
3  False  False  False
```

Or `max`

```
bool_df[~bool_df.max(1)]
     one  three    two
3  False  False  False
```

Comment: thank you so much, I KNOW I wouldn't have thought of this use of sum or max